# Designing circuit involving solenoid

Tags: transistors, switches, diodes

I want to design a circuit to to drive an electromagnet solenoid, over a long piece of cable. The cable could be damaged (short-circuit or open-circuit), so the circuit must detect these conditions. Driving the circuit can be seen later, I just want to know how can we detect these conditions? I would appreciate anyone who could help me with this

Answer (score 2):

You can, in general, detect either condition by monitoring the output current from the driver. If the current is much less than expected a short time after turning it on you know there is an open circuit failure. If the current rises above what is expected then there may may be a short and your circuit can act appropriately to protect the driver.

If you need to detect the conditions with the output off you can pass current (either a small amount that won't cause the solenoid to stick or brief pulses) through the solenoid and monitor the response. Note that you still should deal with the short circuit condition to protect the driver in case the short arises while the solenoid is energized.

Answer (score 0):

The cable length may be such that the solenoid only receives a small fraction of the intended voltage (i.e. it doesn't successfully operate) so, I would consider using a constant current driver so that the solenoid always receives sufficient voltage to energize it.

With a constant current driver it is somewhat inherently protected against short circuits across the line feeding the solenoid but simple voltage monitoring at the send end can usually determine this problem and appropriate action taken.

Don't forget to protect the driver electronics with a flyback diode.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWUrBt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A standard mosfet driver can be used, and with a small modification will do what you want. If we take as an example a 12V solenoid that draws 1A.

The N-channel mosfet Q1 is turned on by applying a 5V signal to its gate through R3. R3 is not always necessary, but it prevents a current spike when the mosfet is turned on due to charging the gate capacitance.

With Q1 on, and without a short or open circuit in the wiring, 1A should flow through R1 producing 1V across it. Feed this to an ADC (analog to digital converter) input on the processor to measure the voltage. You should expect a measurment of around 1V if all is OK, but you need to allow for tolerances, so look for a range of say, 0.8V to 1.2V.

If you measure significantly less than 1V then there is probably a break in the wiring to the solenoid.

If you measure significantly more than 1V then there is probably a short circuit. In this case you must switch off Q1 quickly to avoid overheating it. You will need to switch it off within about 10ms, and while Q1 is turned on you need to constantly check for overcurrent.

The circuit below will limit the short circuit current to approximately 3A. The STD12NF06L has a Vgs(th) (the gate source threshold voltage) of between 1 and 2V. Lets say it is 2V. When the voltage across R1 increases to 3V (equivalent to 3A) the voltage between gate and source is no longer high enough to keep the mosfet turned fully on. It will enter a linear mode, and limit the current to about 3A. You must turn off Q1 quickly, and not leave it in current limit for any length of time because it will suffer from thermal runaway.

R2/C1 form a low-pass filter to get rid of some noise and spikes that may come back from your long wire to the solenoid. And if that fails then D2 will clamp the spikes to 5V.